# How do I make the body of a v-card (so the v-card-text) scrollable?

Tags: vue.js, scroll, vuetify.js

Basically, I want to do something similar to what is shown [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#scrollable), but not in a dialog.

In the link, it is a dialog panel that has the card body able to scroll, but I want to have this happen on any specific v-card on the page, not a dialog. When I apply `overflow-y: auto;` to the v-card, the v-card-title is scrolled up too. When I apply `overflow-y: auto;` to anything else in the v-card, nothing changes. I'm using vue and vuetify, but I'm open to adding a new dependency if it will make this work and look nice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried giving the v-card height or max-height style?

Comment: This only works if I know the height of the v-card. My height of the card is set by one of my dependencies (so it is static on render), but I don't know how to get it.